# Why don't Battlestars have guns to protect their landing bays?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004, battlestar-galactica-1978

I was re-watching the *Battlestar Galactica* (1978) and have a  question. In the episode "Fire in Space" the Cylons go right into the landing bay and cause a fire. Why don't the battlestars have guns to protect the landing bays? Not sure it ever happened in the 2004 series: a Cylon causing damage to the landing bays.

Comment: Present-day aircraft carriers have guns such as Phalanx to defend against missile attacks on the ship but none have defences against an enemy aircraft landing on the deck specifically

Comment: There are a number [(500+)](https://en.battlestarwikiclone.org/wiki/Galactica_type_battlestar#Armament) of point defence turrets on a Battlestar, similar to the Phalanx system mentioned by @Gaius, you could say that these perform the function your question concerns, although, as stated, stopping an actual enemy entry to the landing bay is probably not possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you watch closely, you can see nearby guns firing at the approaching cylon raider, however they miss.
Similar to flak in ww2.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! You could improve your answer by [edit]ing in a screenshot of what you are describing